# Open a Bootstrap modal from another modal avoiding .modal-backdrop flashing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I open another modal from a modal by clicking a link inside the first modal (and I also need from te second modal to go back to the first one):

```
<a onclick="$('.modal-1').modal('hide');$('.modal-2').modal('show');"></a>
```

And then in the second modal I can go back to the first via another link:

```
<a onclick="$('.modal-2').modal('hide');$('.modal-1').modal('show');"></a>
```

But doing it this way makes the '.modal-backdrop' flashing, since in the first case the backdrop of the first modal is fading out whilst the second one is fading in.

Could you help me find a way to prevent the backdrop flashing?

Thank you in advance

Comment: instead of opening a new one, just change the content

Comment: Don't use `onclick` attributes. Attach events using correct methods. As you're using jQuery that would be: https://api.jquery.com/on